# HTML row with foreach loop issue

Tags: php, html, foreach, tablerow

I have a main foreach loop and then foreach loops for displaying the tiers and the prices. So below is what I am seeing but it is not working out... I end up with the tiers next to the term like I want it, but the prices end up below the term, not next to the tiers.

```
+----------+--------------------+----------------+
|          |       tier1        |   price1       |
|          +--------------------+----------------+
|   term1  |       tier2        |   price2       |
|          +--------------------+----------------+
|          |       tier3        |   price3       |
+----------+--------------------+----------------+
|          |                    |                |
|          +--------------------+----------------+
|   term2  |                    |                |
```

Comment: Need your css, html, php to help at all...

Comment: Please, use the preview available when you write your question to check that the format is what you want it to be.

Comment: Sounds like you're using some template. Please show some final HTML code generated? And CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Save the number of elements and put it on the **rowspan** attribute:

```
<td rowspan="<?php echo $elements; ?>">
     term1
</td>
```

You can find a nice example of the rowspan attribute here: http://www.angelfire.com/fl5/html-tutorial/tables/tr_code.htm